# Conversion from 'const char *' to 'unsigned char *' in C++?

Tags: c++

I have an encryption function declared as follows: `int encrypt(unsigned char* keydata, int keydata_len, unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *ciphertext)`. This works perfectly and now I call it according to the given snippet.

```
const char *password = "password";
len = encrypt(password, (int)strlen(password), (unsigned char*)(content.c_str()), (int)strlen(content.c_str()), ciphertext);
```

On compiling the C++ code I get an error as:

```
crest.cc:52:13: error: no matching function for call to 'encrypt'
      len = encrypt(password, (int)strlen(password), (unsigned char*)(content.c_str()), (int)strlen(content.c_str()), ciphertext);
            ^~~~~~~
./aes.h:10:5: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char *' to 'unsigned char *' for 1st argument
int encrypt(unsigned char* keydata, int keydata_len, unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *ciphertext);
```

What is the correct way to typecast in C++ to get around this error ?

Comment: You will need to copy the password into writeable memory as `keydata` is not expecting a `const` pointer so may change the contents of that memory location.

Comment: Also, use the appropriate casts in c++.

Comment: I'm confused, since you cast every parameter (including the ones that don't need it) _except_ the one it's telling you to cast, and then you ask how to cast?

Comment: And make this buffer an array or `unsigned char`.

Comment: Also, `strlen(password)` is wrong, because I'm pretty sure that's supposed to be the size of the output buffer.  And `strlen(content.c_str())` is technically correct, but absurd.

Comment: Also, don't tag C++ questions with the C tag.

Comment: Neither removing constness not coercing `char *` to `unsigned char *` should be implicit.  Removing constness is highly suspicious, but so it the prototype for `encrypt()`: why does it need to modify the `plaintext` buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with this code, and the only (correct) way to fix them is to ensure that you use the correct data types in the first place.

So, instead of `const char *password = "password"`, use `unsigned char password[] = "password";` (of course, this will probably give you trouble with `strlen`, since it won't like `unsigned char`) - using `sizeof(password)-1` will work in THIS instance, but is ill advised as a general solution, since `password` may well be not be directly available as an array - not sure quite what you should do as an "ideal" solution, really.

Now, the question can be asked whether it is actually correct to have a non-const input to the function. If you have the source for `encrypt`, you may want to change the function to `encrypt(const unsigned char* keydata, size_t keydata_len, const unsigned char* plaintext, size_t plaintext_len, unsigned char* ciphertext)` - still doesn't fix the problem with `strlen` of `unsigned char` of course, but it's what I'd expect the prototype to be for a function like this.

An alternative would be to rewrite the `encrypt` function to make casts to `unsigned` only internally, and use `char *` inputs (with `const` where relevant).

Note that it's NOT valid to cast away constness EXCEPT for cases where you know that the original content is not `const` (which I think is NOT guaranteed to be the case for `std::string::c_str()`, but `std::string::data()` should work)

Comment: It is OK to use `const char *password` and cast, because `char` can be aliased as `unsigned char`. In practice I  usually go with whichever option will mean the least casting, and we ignore the possibility of non-2's complement systems with negative chars (because many other problems would also crop up on such systems)

Comment: Uhm, it's not, generally, ok to cast `const` away from a constant string. It is most likely not writeable - so if it was really "non-const" for some "good reason" (it gets modified) then it's definitely a problem to cast it. Yes, you can cast `char*` to `unsigned char*`, that's typically fine.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting casting away const

Comment: But the original prototype in the question REQUIRES the `const` to be cast away.

Comment: Yes, the prototype should be fixed but I'm saying that `const char *` etc. is a viable option